# Finding limits of integration for a improper integral

Tags: probability

We have $X$ exponential with parameter $\lambda$ and $Y$ uniform on $[0,1]$. We wanna find the density of $X+Y$. we have

$$ f_{X+Y}(a) = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(a-x) dx$$

Now, we must have $x>0$ and $0 \leq a-x \leq 1 $. Now, we have $x \leq a $ but $a \leq x+1$. can We just integrate from $x=a-1$ to $x=a$??

My notes consider two cases differently when $a<1$ and when $a \geq 1$. Why do we need to break it up in cases?

Comment: There's a conflict of role of $a$: change the variable in $f_{X+Y}$.

Comment: Is $Y$ uniform on $[0,1]$ rather than $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that both $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are defined piecewisely. So in fact,

$$ f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf{1}_{\{x \geq 0\}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_Y(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{1}_{\{a \leq x \leq b\}}. $$

Now if $X,Y$ are independent so that we can utilize the convolution formula, we have

$$ f_{X+Y}(z)
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) \, dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf{1}_{\{x \geq 0\}} \cdot \frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{1}_{\{a \leq z-x \leq b\}} \, dx. $$

The catch is that, the limits of integration is determined by how the product of indicator functions simplifies. Indeed,

$$ \mathbf{1}_{\{x \geq 0\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{a \leq z-x \leq b\}}
= \mathbf{1}_{\{ x \in [0,\infty) \cap [z-b,z-a] \}} $$

and $ [0,\infty) \cap [z-b,z-a] = [\max\{0,z-b\}, \max\{0, z-a\}]$. Using this we can get rid of the indicator function and write

$$ f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{\max\{0,z-b\}}^{\max\{0,z-a\}} \frac{\lambda}{b-a}e^{-\lambda x} \, dx. $$

Of course, using $\max$ funcion here is a convenient technique, and you can always count on case division.